# How to fit all text at the bottom of the graph Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am displaying a graph of the classifier and below is the output of the process. The fact is that my text does not fit into the displayed area, and in order to see it, I have to open the parameters of the chart itself, which is not very convenient.

The plot is displayed through a separate function, where arguments are passed:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def visualize_classifier(classifier, x, y, heading = None, view_result = None):

    min_x, max_x = x[:, 0].min() - 1.0, x[:, 0].max() + 1.0
    min_y, max_y = x[:, 1].min() - 1.0, x[:, 1].max() + 1.0

    mesh_step_size = 0.01
    x_vals, y_vals = np.meshgrid(np.arange(min_x, max_x, mesh_step_size), np.arange(min_y, max_y, mesh_step_size))

    output = classifier.predict(np.c_[x_vals.ravel(), y_vals.ravel()])
    output = output.reshape(x_vals.shape)

    plt.figure()
    plt.pcolormesh(x_vals, y_vals, output, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    plt.scatter(x[:, 0], x[:, 1], c=y, s=75, edgecolors='black', linewidth=1, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)


    plt.xlim(x_vals.min(), x_vals.max())
    plt.ylim(y_vals.min(), y_vals.max())


    plt.xticks((np.arange(int(x[:, 0].min() - 1), int(x[:, 0].max() + 1), 1.0)))
    plt.yticks((np.arange(int(x[:, 1].min() - 1), int(x[:, 1].max() + 1), 1.0)))

    if view_result != None:
        plt.xlabel(view_result)

    if heading != None:
        plt.title(heading)

    plt.show()
```

And here is the function from which I call it:

```
def nbc_with_validation():
    title = 'Наивный байесовый классификатор с перекрестной проверкой'
    result_view = ("Точность нового классификатора = " + str(round(accuracy, 2)) + "%\n" +
                   "Accuracy: " + str(round(100*accuracy_values.mean(), 2)) + "%\n" +
                   "Precision: " + str(round(100*precision_values.mean(), 2)) + "%\n" +
                   "Recall: " + str(round(100*recall_values.mean(), 2)) + "%\n" +
                   "F1: " + str(round(100*f1_values.mean(), 2)) + "%")

    visualize_classifier(classifier_new, X_1, y_1, title, result_view)
```

I get this in the output:

[image]

And I would like this:

[image]

How to change the parameters of the chart output?

Comment: Usually, calling `plt.tight_layout()` just before `plt.show()` would fit all texts nicely.

Comment: Use constrained_layout.